# Почему при отправке данных на почте пустые сроки?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, phpmailer

На сайте есть форма, когда сабмичу выходит алерт "Данные отправлены", на самой почте данные отсутствуют (в таком случае я прописала что "данные были утеряны" в коде).

Почему так происходит?

Использую PHPMailer для отправки на почту. В девтулсах смотрю в нетворк данные отправленные отображаются.

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    //Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(

      'ssl' => array(

        'verify_peer' => false,

        'verify_peer_name' => false,

        'allow_self_signed' => true

      )

    );
    $mail->isSMTP(); //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru';  //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username  = 'username'; //SMTP username
    $mail->Password  = 'password';  //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->setFrom("username", "Линия доставки");
    // send to
    $mail->addAddress("username", "Линия доставки");

    $theme = '[ДАННЫЕ ИЗ ФОРМЫ ЛИНИЯ ДОСТАВКИ]';
    $mail->Subject = $theme;

    // letter's body
    $body = '<h1>Данные формы:</h1>';

    if(isset($_POST["tel"])){
        $tel = $_POST["tel"];
    }else{
        $tel = "Данные телефона были утерены";
    }

    if (trim(!empty($tel))) {
        $body .= '<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ' . $tel . '</p>';
    }

    $mail->Body = $body;

    // send
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $message = 'Ошибка';
    } else {
        $message = 'Данные отправлены!';
    }

    $response = ['message' => $message];

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);

    $mail->smtpClose();
?>
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST) - отображает данные которые вы передаете через форму?

Comment: @ioszhuk Если правильно вставила в код, то вот {"message":"\u0414\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u044b!"}array(0) {
}

Comment: ничего не понятно) учитесь пользоваться сервисами скринов плз.. вот: joxi.ru к примеру.. из того что вы скинули могу увидеть только слово "message", а параметра "tel" нету тут.

Comment: @ioszhuk потому что это ответ, а не запрос

Comment: как вы данные передаете в эту форму? у вас пустой массив в _POST вывелся. ну или что там в девтулсах у вас. Подозерваю, что там не пост с полями, а json в body и отправляете это аяксом

Comment: так что какой-нить `$input = json_decode("php://input"); $tel = $input->tel;`

Comment: @teran да я использую angular и HttpClient и там получается:

```
sendQuery (data: any) {
    return this.http.post('https://deline24.ru/send/sendtel.php', data);
  }
```

Comment: @teran
Сама функция отправки:

```
submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      console.log(this.form.value)
      this.appService.sendQuery(this.form.value)
        .subscribe(
          {
            next: (response: any) => {
              alert(response.message);
              this.form.reset();
            },
            error: (response) => {
              alert(response.error.message);
            }
          }
        );
   }  
}
```

Comment: @ioszhuk там написано "Данные отправлены"array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. С фронта приходили данные в формате JSON, но в PHP-скрипте использовалась суперглобальная переменная $_POST, которая принимала данные в виде array, а надо было в string. $_POST была заменена на file_get_contents('php://input').

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

  //Load Composer's autoloader
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->SMTPOptions = array(

    'ssl' => array(

      'verify_peer' => false,

      'verify_peer_name' => false,

      'allow_self_signed' => true

    )

  );
  $mail->isSMTP(); //Send using SMTP
  $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru';  //Set the SMTP server to send through
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  //Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username  = '****@yandex.ru'; //SMTP username
  $mail->Password  = '****';  //SMTP password
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  //Enable implicit TLS encryption
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
  $mail->IsHTML(true);

  $mail->setFrom("****@yandex.ru", "Линия доставки");
  // send to
  $mail->addAddress("****@yandex.ru", "Линия доставки");

  $theme = '[ДАННЫЕ ИЗ ФОРМЫ ЛИНИЯ ДОСТАВКИ]';
  $mail->Subject = $theme;

  // letter's body
  $body = '<h1>Данные формы:</h1>';

  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

  $data = json_decode($json, true);

  if (trim(!empty($data['tel']))) {
    $tel = $data['tel'];
    $body .= '<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ' . $tel . '</p>';
  }else{
    $body .= '<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ' . 'Данные телефона были утеряны' . '</p>';
  }

  $mail->Body = $body;

  // send
  if (!$mail->send()) {
    $message = 'Ошибка';
  } else {
    $message = 'Данные отправлены!';
  }

  $response = ['message' => $message];

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);

  $mail->smtpClose();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. возьмите в try\catch весь код отправки $mail.
2. вы папку спам проверяли у получателя письма?
3. $mail->smtpClose(); лучше разместить перед $response
4. после $mail->send(), выведите var_dump($mail->ErrorInfo), может все-таки есть ошибки.